# Sequelize 'where' on parent and child when parent hasMany childs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 models:

```
class User extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      User.hasMany(models.Role, {
        foreignKey: 'userId'
      });
    }
  };
  User.init({
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    lastname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    allowedApps: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM({
        values: Object.keys(PORTALS)
      }),
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    paranoid: true,
    modelName: 'User',
  });

class Role extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Role.BelongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'userId'
      });
    }
  };
  Role.init({
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    paranoid: true,
    modelName: 'Role',
  });
```

I would like to get all users where the firstname OR the role type matches a certain condition. Something like:

```
User
    .findAndCountAll({
        where: {
            $or: [
         {
            firstname: "John Doe"
         },
         {
            "$Role.type$": "Admin"
         }
       ]
        },
        include: [{
            model: Role,
        }],
    }).limit=10,offset=0
    .then(users => res.status(200).send(users))
    .catch(error => {
        return res.sendStatus(500);
    });
```

above query giving me error: **"SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'Role.type' in 'field list'"**

I want to search through child model when it has one to many relationship having my limit and offset intact.Same query would give me success if user would have *HasOne* relation with role.
This is just an example code of what I try to achieve so please ignore any typos and silly mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging:

```
await User.findAll({
where: {
            $or: [
         {
            firstname: "John Doe"
         },
         {
            "$Role.type$": "Admin"
         }
       ]
        },
  include: {
    model: Role,
    as: 'Role',
    required: false
  }
});
```

However, it doesn't make logical sense to select Users that have no associated Role (`required: false`), while querying such Users with a property that exists on Role ($or: $Role.type$). If we set `Required = true`, then we violate your initial condition

> firstname OR the role type matches a certain condition.

The following addresses this problem:

```
await User.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Role,
    required: false
  }
})
.then(
  users => users
    .filter(user => user?.firstName === "John Doe" || user.role?.type === 
    "Admin");
);
```

Comment: field 'type' belongs to child model ...So still can't access it